# Passing input value to vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component

I'm new in vuejs and I was creating custom components for elements like buttons, links, inputs, etc.
This is my input component-

```js
<template>
  <div class="position-relative">
    <input
      :class="[{ 'pe-5': type === 'password' }, 'form-control p-2 rounded-3']"
      :type="inputType"
      :id="label ? slugify(label) : null"
      v-model="inputValue"
      v-bind="$attrs"
    />
    <CustomButton
      type="button"
      transparent
      class="position-absolute end-0 top-50 translate-y--50"
      v-if="type === 'password'"
      @click="togglePasswordVisibility"
    >
      <RemixIcon :icon="showPassword ? 'eye-off-line' : 'eye-line'" />
    </CustomButton>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import RemixIcon from '../components/RemixIcon.vue';
import CustomButton from '../components/CustomButton.vue';

export default {
  components: {
    RemixIcon,
    CustomButton
  },
  props: {
    type: {
      type: String,
      default: 'text',
    },
    label: {
      type: String,
      default: '',
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      inputValue: '',
      showPassword: false,
    };
  },
  computed: {
    inputType() {
      return this.showPassword ? 'text' : this.type;
    },
  },
  methods: {
    togglePasswordVisibility() {
      this.showPassword = !this.showPassword;
    },
    slugify(str) {
      return str
        .toLowerCase()
        .trim()
        .replace(/[^\w\s-]/g, '')
        .replace(/[\s_-]+/g, '-')
        .replace(/^-+|-+$/g, '');
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped></style>
```

When I use v-model on it, It doesn't work properly

```js
<TextInput type="text" v-model="user_name" />
```

In this case `user_name` has a default value but It doesn't appear in input.

I want to use v-model with this input and make it useable.

I tried searching online and asked from AI tools but nothing worked for me.

Comment: have you read [this documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html#component-v-model) ... since you have no `modelValue` prop, nor are you emitting an `update:modelValue` event, I take it you have not read that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@jaromanda-x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77248669/passing-input-value-to-vue-component/77249138?noredirect=1#comment136184687_77248669) mentioned, I added `:value` in my custom component and triggered an `$emit` for updating value of input. This is the final result that I ended up with -

```
<template>
  <div class="position-relative">
    <input
      :class="[{ 'pe-5': type === 'password' }, 'form-control p-2 rounded-3']"
      :type="inputType"
      :value="modelValue"
      @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)"
    />
    <CustomButton
      type="button"
      transparent
      class="position-absolute end-0 top-50 translate-y--50"
      v-if="type === 'password'"
      @click="togglePasswordVisibility"
    >
      <RemixIcon :icon="showPassword ? 'eye-off-line' : 'eye-line'" />
    </CustomButton>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import RemixIcon from '../components/RemixIcon.vue';
import CustomButton from '../components/CustomButton.vue';

export default {
  components: {
    RemixIcon,
    CustomButton
  },
  props: {
    type: {
      type: String,
      default: 'text',
    },
    label: {
      type: String,
      default: '',
    },
    modelValue: {
      type: String,
    }
  },
  emits: ['update:modelValue'],
  data() {
    return {
      inputValue: '',
      showPassword: false,
    };
  },
  computed: {
    inputType() {
      return this.showPassword ? 'text' : this.type;
    },
  },
  methods: {
    togglePasswordVisibility() {
      this.showPassword = !this.showPassword;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Now I can use `v-model` on this component and It's working as expected.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you can see the [docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html), you must update the value  in custom components